# Radio button + click non-radio button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a quiz for an online bootcamp. I'm trying to make it so that when the user clicks a true or false radio button and then clicks the "next" button, the score is updated and the next question is displayed. I'm trying to use line 30-32 of the Javascript to do this, but am not quite sure how to implement it. It is currently preventing my app from running when it is not commented out.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quiz.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="quiz.js"></script>
    <title>Pokemon Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pokemon Quiz! Test your skill!</h1>
    <button id="reset" type="button">Reset Quiz</button>
    <form>
      <h3 class="anchor"></h3><br>
      <input type="radio" name="T/F" id="true">True<br>
      <input type="radio" name="T/F" id="false">False
      <br><button type="button" id="next">Next/Start</button><br>
    </form>
    <p>Score: <span id="score">0</span></p>
    <p>Question No. <span id="questionnum">0</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    color: #00CCFF;
    background-image: url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/vyY0jRjrTy4/maxresdefault.jpg);
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
form {
    margin-left: 45px;
}
input {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
P {
    color: yellow;
    margin-left: 150px;
}
#next {
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: red;
}
#reset {
    margin-left: 135px;
    color: red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //game();
    questionNumber = 0;
    score = 0;
    if (questionNumber < questions.length) {
        $('#next').click(function(){
        game();
        questionNumber ++;
        });
    };

    $('#reset').click(function(){
        neu();
        game();
    });

});

function neu() {
    questionNumber = 0;
    score = 0;
}

function game() {
    console.log(questionNumber);
    $("h3.anchor").html(questions[questionNumber]);

    //if radiobutton value == answers[questionNumber]

    if ((document.getElementById("true").checked && answers[questionNumber] == true) || (document.getElementById("false").checked && answers[questionNumber] == false) {
        score ++;
    }

/*
    if(document.getElementById("next").clicked == true) {
        if(document.getElementById("true").checked) {
            score++;
            console.log(score);
        }
        console.log(score);
        $(".anchor").html("There are 9 certified Pokemon League badges?");
    }
    */
}

//Use use question number to access array values (questions)
//consider using object instead of array to allow for boolean values
//var questions = [];
questions = ["Caterpie evolves into Metapod?",
"There are 9 certified Pokemon League badges?",
"Poliwag evolves 3 times?",
"Are thunder moves effective against ground-type Pokemon?",
"Pokemon of the same kind and level are not identical?",
"TM28 contains Tombstony?"];

answers = [true, false, false, false, true, false];
```

Comment: "*It is currently preventing my app from running*" means? Any error in the console?

Comment: Well, for one thing, there is no global "questionNumber", so game() should be getting some kind of error when it tries to use that variable.